# How do I open a file without blocking in windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

I see the CreateFile function takes in a FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED parameter to make the file io non blocking. However, how can I make the CreateFile call itself non-blocking?

Comment: StorageFolder::CreateFileAsync() is winapi++.  Nothing very mystical, it simply runs on a threadpool thread.  You can do that too of course.

Comment: `StorageFolder` is only available to Windows Store apps, not standard Win32 apps.

Comment: @Remy Which is why Hans suggests using the threadpool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `CreateFile` is synchronous. If you need it to be non-blocking, you are probably trying to do I/O in the UI thread. Avoid that.

You did not mention the programming language, so I will assume it is C++. You can use [the standard library's threading facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) to offload the I/O intensive work into a worker thread. For example, you could wrap it in a [packaged_task](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task) or [async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

Comment: I know I can use worker threads, and it is currently the solution I am implementing. I was wondering if it is possible to do this purely using async and non blocking IO though. I am trying to optimize a job that transfers large number of files.  The language is python but I am fairly comfortable using low level windows API calls from python.

Comment: There is no async/nonblocking version of `CreateFile()` available. Like doug said, `CreateFile()` itself is synchronous only.